# How do I start an elevated process with schtasks.exe?

Tags: windows-10, uac, schtasks

## GUI vs Command-Line

The task scheduler GUI provides an option to run the scheduled task in an elevated context ("Run with highest privileges"), e.g.

[image: Scheduled Task Properties (emphasis added)]

I cannot find a [corresponding flag for schtasks.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks#schtasks-create). The closest thing I can find is to export an existing task (created with the GUI) with that property set and import it (and potentially modify it later).

Is there another way to create a scheduled task in an elevated process?

Answer (score 1):

The option you are looking for is `/RL`:

> ```
>    /RL   level        Sets the Run Level for the job. Valid values are
>                       LIMITED and HIGHEST. The default is LIMITED.
> ```

The documentation doesn't indeed mention it, probably by mistake; but the command help (`schtasks.exe /create /?`) does.